# For google map route do we really need internet connection

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on a assignment in which there is a need to calculate latitude and longitude of source and destination and based on source and destination lat long, i need to draw a route on google map between source and destination. so to complete this assignment, do i really need internet? if yes, so at what point i need internet connection while completing this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- GPS **does not** need an internet connection
- display the map **might not** need internet in case that the area is in the cache of the google map application, otherwise internet is necessary
- calculating a route between two points **does need** an internet connection

Comment: Google Maps 5.7 introduced the possibility of downloading map areas for offline use - check this link for details [click](http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2011/07/download-map-area-added-to-labs-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

Mainly used in google map itself need to use internet first thing than the another thing was find the route between two point.

Other thing like calculate the distance that was comes in the direction in google map also you can get the more detail about this route for this two point of location.

and to draw the route between this two point no another need to use Internet.

for query the direction route you need to use internet for google direction api

Comment: we can find the lattitude and longitude without using internet as device gps co-ordinate would be use

Answer (score 0):

GPS does not need internet (though if you provide internet you will get a location faster). 
You can get the latitude and longitude information and record it the way you like to.

But when you want to display this recorded route on Google Maps, you will need teh internets.

Comment: at what point i will need internet when i will try to draw it on google map?

Comment: It depends on what you're doing. When you start using the `MapView` class. or when you invoke Google Maps with [intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html)